# Safari 5 bug - Radio button's checked="checked" attribute is ignored when loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, safari, checkedlistbox, radio-button

Strange bug with Safari happening when a radio button input is loaded via AJAX.  The relavent code is

```
<input type="radio" name="team" value="231" style="width:auto;" checked="checked"/>Team 1

<input type="radio" name="team" value="232" style="width:auto;"/>Team 2
```

When this code is loaded with plain old html, the first radio button is checked as it should be.  But if the same exact code is loaded via ajax, Safari doesn't actually show any indication it is checked, even though the checked="checked" attribute is there in the source.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I was out of town on vacation with no internet access. 

Doctype is 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: There is additional information in the [stackoverflow question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340345/safari-ajax-bug-checked-radio-not-checked